# Find line with text in a file

Tags: java

I wanted to find out in options.bldata if firstLaunch= was written, for this I wrote the following code:

```
File file = new File("options.bldata");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        if (line == "firstLaunch=") {
            
            System.out.println("123");
            
        }
        
    }
```

when it finds a line with firstLaunch= it should print 123, but I don't know why it doesn't print 123 even if firstLaunch= is in the file.

Comment: Does this answer your question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java/513839#513839

Answer (score 2):

Operator == checks if both objects point to the same memory location whereas .equals() evaluates to the comparison of values in the objects.

```
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) { 
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        if (line.equals("firstLaunch=")) {   
            System.out.println("123");   
        }   
    }
```

Here is an article for more [information](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-equals-method-java/)

Answer (score 1):

There is two wrong thing in the code.

1. Never use double equals to compare strings. You need to use the `equals()` function from string to do so
2. you want to test if the string `firstLaunch=` is in the line, not that your line is equals to `firstLaunch=`. For this, you can use `line.contains("firstLaunch=")`

Answer (score 1):

You should use `equals()` to compare strings. Or in your case, `contains()` because the line might have other stuff, not just what you want to find